# Trouble using TTL serial USB converter with CP2102

Tags: linux, putty, raspberry-pi2, uart

I bought a serial TTL to USB converter for monitoring my raspberry, but got stuck while booting. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.4.6

http://www.amazon.de/USB-TTL-Konverter-Modul-mit-eingebautem-CP2102/dp/B00AFRXKFU?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

(RaspberryPi with raspbian)

```
nano /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootflags=commit=120  elevator=deadline noatime nodiratime fsck.repair=yes data=writeback rootwait
```

Driver is working fine.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

logging:

```
dmsg
[19265.407597] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[19265.407603] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[19265.407606] usb 2-1.2: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[19265.407609] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[19265.407612] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0001
[19265.408610] cp210x 2-1.2:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[19265.408791] usb 2-1.2: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

connecting wires:

- TX <-> RX
- RX <-> TX
- GRD <-> GRD

starting putty: `sudo putty`
settings:

- Serial line to connect to /dev/ttyUSB1
- Speed (baud) 115200
- Data bits 8
- Stop bits 1
- Parity None
- Flow control None

Serial terminal shows only one line and get stops working:

```
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

No more text.. and I can not press any key.

Any suggestion, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `console=ttyAMA0,115200` instead. Assuming your serial adapter is connected correctly (judging from the early lines, it is), you have just configured the `console` bootarg incorrectly.

To elaborate, the reason you get that one line is because the early bootcode doesn't care about the `console` bootarg, it'll write that line using a small UART driver embedded in the decompressor routine.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! :)  `console=serial0,115200` is copied from a buildroot tutorial. Why would you use serial0? Or is this an alias for ttyAMA0?

Comment: I'm not sure but I've always used `ttyAMA0` so I know it works. If you found my answer helpful, accepting it would be appreciated ^^

Comment: figured out `console=serial0,115200` is default from raspbian lite.